# Change the background of Cells with C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, cell, worksheet

I'm developing an program using C# to manipulate an Excel document, and I'm using

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet;
```

When I insert something to a x,y cell I use :

```
worksheet.Cells[x, y] = "something";
```

Now I want to know if it's possible to change the `backColor` of the Cells[x,y] from C#.

Thank you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try

```
worksheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color
```

You won't be able to use the Colors in .Net directly, they will require a translation.

It is recommended to use the following (obviously change from silver) :

```
worksheet.Cells[x, y].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Silver);
```

Comment: cannot use Interior. There is an error like the excel object doesn't have definition for that keyword.

Comment: Excel interop 14.0 allows you to set colors without ColorTranslator, using `Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbSilver`

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can color a cell or a entire column or entire row.

The below code will help you out.

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
```

else

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3], xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3]).Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
```

Here **xlWorksheet** is the object excel Worksheet object.

**get_Range** takes 2 variable one start cell and other is end cell.

so if you specify both the values same then only one cell is colored.

**xlWorkSheet.cells[row, column]** is used to specify a cell.

**System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(SystemDrawing.Color.Green)** is used to define the color in OLE format.

**Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed** is a excel way of coloring the cells
This method gives access to large number of colors which can be found here [list of colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlrgbcolor.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
private static readonly int DEL_PERF_FIRST_DATA_ROW = 10;
private static readonly int SUN_ORDERS_COLUMN = 3;
private static readonly int TUE_ORDERS_COLUMN = 5;
private static readonly int THU_ORDERS_COLUMN = 7;
private static readonly int SAT_ORDERS_COLUMN = 9;
private static Color ALTERNATE_WEEKDAY_COLUMNS_COLOR = Color.LightGray;
. . .
int curRow = DEL_PERF_FIRST_DATA_ROW;
```

(curRow gets incremented each time a row is written to the sheet.)

```
// Pale Violetize (light gray, actually) Sun, Tues, Thurs, and Saturday columns
var sundayColumnRange = _xlSheetDelPerf.Range[_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[DEL_PERF_FIRST_DATA_ROW, SUN_ORDERS_COLUMN],_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curRow - 1, SUN_ORDERS_COLUMN]];
sundayColumnRange.Interior.Color = ALTERNATE_WEEKDAY_COLUMNS_COLOR;

var tuesdayColumnRange = _xlSheetDelPerf.Range[_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[DEL_PERF_FIRST_DATA_ROW, TUE_ORDERS_COLUMN],_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curRow - 1, TUE_ORDERS_COLUMN]];
tuesdayColumnRange.Interior.Color = ALTERNATE_WEEKDAY_COLUMNS_COLOR;

var thursdayColumnRange = _xlSheetDelPerf.Range[_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[DEL_PERF_FIRST_DATA_ROW, THU_ORDERS_COLUMN],_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curRow - 1, THU_ORDERS_COLUMN]];
thursdayColumnRange.Interior.Color = ALTERNATE_WEEKDAY_COLUMNS_COLOR;

var saturdayColumnRange =_xlSheetDelPerf.Range[_xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[DEL_PERF_FIRST_DATA_ROW, SAT_ORDERS_COLUMN], _xlSheetDelPerf.Cells[curRow - 1, SAT_ORDERS_COLUMN]];
saturdayColumnRange.Interior.Color = ALTERNATE_WEEKDAY_COLUMNS_COLOR;
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who want to set Hex color to the background can use:

```cs
worksheet.get_Range("A1", "F1").Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#52b69a");
```