# DataGridView To Excel With Colored Cells

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I looked a lots of example and demo but I could not to it.

I'm trying to convert datagridview to excel.

My Results
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6WlF.png

But its convert to excel like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iK5a.png

I want to copy cells size and color but how?

I convert to excel with this code

```
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Int16 i, j;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FileName = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " " + listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() + " Stok Reçeteleri" + ".xls";


        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //ToCsV(dataGridView1, sfd.FileName); // Here dataGridview1 is your grid view name
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            //xlWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.X
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(sfd.FileName);
        }


        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: You might be best using epplus https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus instead of the office interop stuff - especially server side.

Comment: Yes, use EPPlus instead of Interop.  Interop should only be a last resort, and even then you should rethink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update the internal loop to be:

```
for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                {
                    Range range = (Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1];
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
                    range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor );

                }
            }
```

don't forget:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

see: 
 [Change the background of Cells with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6059339/992406)

Comment: I just change this line like this
range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(dgv.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor );

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for exporting to excel instead of what you are using. I use this for web apps though.

```
private void ExportGridToExcel()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Charset = "";
    string FileName = "SomeFileName" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
    StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
    GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    GridView1.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
    Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
       server control at run time. */
}
```